# Python 3.2 SQLite 3 Error with connect function

Tags: python, sqlite

I try to learn SQL and I do that with Python 3.2. I know that SQLite3 module is installed with Python, but when I try to do this code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
```

I got this error: Undefined variable from import: connect

I have checked In usr/lib and the .so file is there..

What can I do to solve that ?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're using pydev.

Try it in non-pydev environ.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
```

**UPDATE:** The actual fix for this problem is given in the following [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.plugins.pydev.user/5012)

Comment: @abuteau, Did you build python yourself?

Comment: No..Installing via apt-get on linux with sudo apt-get install python3-all

Comment: @abuteau, What is the result of `ls /usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload/*sqlite*so`?

Comment: /usr/lib/python3.2/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-32mu.so

Comment: Should i reinstall with python3.2 only (not the mu)

Comment: @abuteau, [This link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.plugins.pydev.user/5012) may help you.

Comment: @abuteau that solved my problem, as I was experience this exact behaviour. Thank you!